# Flutter Navigation is not smooth, taking time to open next screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a Quiz app which load text from a List of String class using **ListViewBuilder**. When i click on a category the question list is taking time to open 3-4 seconds. Here question in **QuestionCategory** is one for demo purpose. In real app it has 200+ question and the Navigation problem comes where question list is around more than 100+. The related question is already asked but the there is no proper solution for this.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:himachal_gk/Model/question_model.dart';
import 'package:himachal_gk/Widget/style_widgets.dart';
import '../../../Ads/GoogleAds.dart';
import 'category_question.dart';

class CategoryWiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryWiseScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var category = [
      'River',
      // 'Books',
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Category Wise GK"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Favorite');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded))
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: GoogleAds.getBottomBannerAd(context),
      body: AnimationLimiter(
        child: ListView.builder(
          cacheExtent: 9999999,
          itemCount: category.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
              position: index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
              child: SlideAnimation(
                verticalOffset: 50.0,
                child: FadeInAnimation(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SubCategoryTiles(
                        categoryIcon: Icons.school,
                        titleText: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            category[index],
                            style: headingTextStyle,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTapHandler: () {
                          if (index == 0) {
                            List<QuestionCategory> questionCategory = [
                              QuestionCategory(
                                  question:
                                      'How many rivers are there in Himachal Pradesh',
                                  correctAnswer: 'Five'),
                            ];
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              CupertinoPageRoute(
                                builder: ((context) => CategoryQuestion(
                                      title: category[index],
                                      questionCategory: questionCategory,
                                    )),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      const Divider(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is  SubCategoryTiles code we have used in above code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubCategoryTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubCategoryTiles({
    Key? key,
    required this.titleText,
    required this.onTapHandler,
    required this.categoryIcon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget titleText;
  final VoidCallback onTapHandler;
  final IconData categoryIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Icon(
          categoryIcon,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
      title: titleText,
      trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
      onTap: onTapHandler,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is not the problem of navigation, you are observing lag , because of the heavy animation you are trying to make for each child of the listview

Comment: Does this problem persists in release build too?

Comment: yes, this problem is also in Live app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a performance issue. This is caused by two things in your case. First, you are loading heavy data while on a Navigation call. I will advise using `initState` or an `async` function`enter code here` to call data before pushing to any screen.

```dart
    List<QuestionCategory> questionCategory = [
            QuestionCategory(
                question: 'How many rivers are there in Himachal Pradesh',
                correctAnswer: 'Five',
            ),
        ];
```

The above shows, you are calling within `onTapHandler` the same function that pushes to a new screen. In the live app, the Navigation will take time as it has to wait for data to fill in the `questionCategory` .